# SELECT DISTINCT not doing what I would hope it would do

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to bring back a list of properties. Properties can have many "passes". I want to bring back a list of unique properties but if they have multiple passes, I want the one with the largest pass_id. This is what I have so far:

```
select * from passes
inner join properties on properties.prop_id = passes.prop_id
where pass_id NOT IN (select pass_id from queue where user_id = 1)

+---------+---------+---------+---------+------------------+--------------+-------+
| pass_id | prop_id | user_id | prop_id | full_street_name | house_number | zip   |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+------------------+--------------+-------+
|      18 |      21 |       1 |      21 |  N KEELER AVE    |         6200 | 60646 |
|      20 |      21 |       1 |      21 |  N KEELER AVE    |         6200 | 60646 |
|      21 |      21 |       1 |      21 |  N KEELER AVE    |         6200 | 60646 |
|      22 |      22 |       1 |      22 |  E CHESTNUT ST   |          111 | 60611 |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+------------------+--------------+-------+
```

I want it to return only pass_id 21 and 22 since 18 and 20 are duplicate properties of 21. Thanks in advance.

Comment: FYI the answer you accepted is a trivial answer that only works for one property. My answer works for any number of properties, and more particularly works for your query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
 Select * From passes p
 Where Pass_Id =
     (Select Max(pass_Id) From Passes
      Where Prop_Id = p.Prop_Id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you're using mysql, you can use this mysql-only neat solution:

```
select * from (
    select * from passes
    inner join properties on properties.prop_id = passes.prop_id
    where pass_id NOT IN (select pass_id from queue where user_id = 1)
    order by pass_id desc) x
group by prop_id
```

This query is simply your original query but ordered by `pass_id desc`, then grouping by `prop_id`.

In every other database I know, this would cause an SQL syntax exception, because there are columns not being grouped-by that are not aggregated. However, in mysql, instead of giving an error, it returns the *first* row for each group. In this case, the first row is the largest `pass_id` because the data is ordered that way.

Answer (score 0):

Try this?

```
Select * From passes p  
Where Pass_Id in
  (Select [Max] = MAX(Pass_ID) OVER(PARTITION BY Prop_Id) 
   From Passes)
```